# Replace variable value in build.xml using Jenkins file pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, ant, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have created one pipeline script in which I have used Global variable name BRANCH_NAME. Now I want to use that variable value in my build.xml file but I am not able to use that variable.

**Below is my Pipeline script.**

```
script {
    def prjName = 'collaborate_'
    echo "${prjName}${BRANCH_NAME.replace("/","_")}"
    def fullPrjName = "${prjName}${BRANCH_NAME.replace("/","_")}"
    environment{
            sonar.project="${fullPrjName}"
            sonar.projectDir="${WORKSPACE}"
            }
        }
```

**Below is my Build.xml property.**

```
<property name="sonar.project" value="collaborate_develop" />
<property name="sonar.projectKey" value="${sonar.project}" />
<property name="sonar.projectName" value="${sonar.project}" />
```

I want to override value of sonar.project from jenkins pipeline script.

We are using sonarQube analysis target and in that we want to place specific feature branch value as part of sonar.project.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the problem is on jenkins side and not inside your ant task?

Try this, this should work:

```
<target name="test" >
  <property environment="env" />
  <echo>BUILD_NUMBER: ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}</echo>
  <echo>Workspace: ${env.WORKSPACE}</echo>
</target>
```